# How to hide password being displayed while grep process in unix

Tags: java, shell, unix

Below are the piece of codes,

```java
String Password = enigma.decrypt(propFile.getProperty("Password"));
String ptr_sec = presto_cli_path + "/presto --server " + presto_https_server + " --keystore-path " + keystore_path + " --keystore-password " + keystore_password + " --catalog " + presto_catalog + " --schema " + presto_schema + " --user " + presto_user + " -f " + queryFile + " --output-format " + outputFromat + " --password " + Password;
Process p_sec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "bash", "-c", ptr_sec });
```

Above code is available in a JAVA JAR. While the process is running and when i grep using

```
ps -ef|grep criskrep|grep presto
```

its showing the complete string which contains the password as well.

Please help to overcome this isssue.

Comment: So you want to hide the password in your shell but not in Java?

Comment: in Java im not printing it. is this issue related to java source itself ?
Is there anything to do with the option "-c"?

Comment: The command line of processes running on a POSIX-like systems are public knowledge. Don't put any supposedly-secret information there. Find a way to communicate the secret information some other way (such as environment variables or files with the appropriate permissions).

Comment: :( is there any other way to solve it. like placing the details in a file once the string is constructed and execute the file from "exec" method ?

Comment: You could encrypt it using some encryption software and store that encrypted value in the jar.  Then you decrypt it in the code, before you need it.  Not perfect, but it will hide the password from a `grep`.

Comment: its already like that. from the property file, im getting the encrypted password in the JAR and decrypting it and constructing the string to pass it to execution.